# KAFKA Cassandra Source connect

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect, cassandra-3.0

I am using *kafka 2.12-2.2.0.0* with *kafka-connect-cassandra-1.1.0-1.1.0*-all and *apache cassandra 3.0.8* While using Kafka source connecter with cassandra , I am not able to create topic getting below error:

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.InstantiationError: com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger at 
com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger$.apply(Logger.scala:42) at 
kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.(Logging.scala:25)
```

Please suggest what went wrong? A lot of thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch problem. Kafka 2.0 removed log4j, I think

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. It was probably the same as you mentioned.

Comment: Right, the Landoop connectors are built against Kafka 1.1.0